# approximating a maximum function by a differentiable function

Tags: approximation

Is it possible to approximate the $max\{x,y\}$ by a differentiable function?
$f(x,y)=max \{x,y\} ;\ x,y>0$

Answer (score 17):

Yes it is. One possibility is the following: Note that $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
$$ \max\{x,y\} = \frac 12 \bigl( x+ y + \abs{x-y}\bigr), $$
take a differentiable approximation of $\abs\cdot$, for example $\def\abe{\mathop{\rm abs}\nolimits_\epsilon}$$\abe \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ for $\epsilon > 0$ given by
$$ \abe(x) := \sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon}, \quad x \in \mathbb R $$
and define $\max_\epsilon \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ by 
$$ \max\nolimits_\epsilon(x,y) := \frac 12 \bigl( x+y+\abe(x-y)\bigr). $$
Another possibility is to take a smooth [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) $\phi_\epsilon$ and let $\max'_\epsilon :=\mathord\max * \phi_\epsilon$.

Comment: (+1), good advice.  One smoothing I stumbled across recently is $|x| \approx x\operatorname{erf}(ax)$ with $a \gg 1$.  Taking $a=5$ works well enough.

Comment: So how would you approximate the following?  $max(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, where $0 \le x_i \le 100$, $i=1,...,3$ ?

Comment: @Clement Perhaps, you could implement it pairwise?

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility is given by:
\begin{equation}
\max (x,y) \approx \ln(e^x+e^y)
\end{equation}
This approximation doesn't work well for similar values of $x$ and $y$. We can however, remedy this by introducing a scaling parameter $N$:
\begin{equation}
\max (x,y) \approx \frac1N\ln(e^{N x}+e^{N y})
\end{equation}
for large values of $N$.

A general definition is given by:

\begin{equation}
\max\limits_{x \in S} \approx \frac1N\ln(\sum\limits_{x\in S} e^{N x})
\end{equation}

Note that in practice $e^{Nx}$ will give unworkably large answers for large $N$.

Comment: How could deal with overflow and underflow in case of large numbers multiplied by large scaling parameter N?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I said it is unworkable for large N.

Comment: I'm testing another function $max(x,y) = pow((pow(x,n) + pow(y,n), 1/n)$ it is doesn't have overflow but in one case when x or y is zero so I'm adding this small number 1e-5 to avoid it. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: That doesn't work for negative numbers.
Why avoid zero? $0^x = 0$ (except $0^0$, but $n \neq 0$ anyway)

Comment: I have relu function before So I don't have any negative numbers. the problem with zero when the function is in its first derivative.

Comment: Overflow issues can be (mostly) avoided using the identity ln(sum(exp(Nn)))/N = ln(sum(exp(N(n-m))))/N + m, where m is the actual maximum.

Comment: $\max(x,x)=x\ne 0.30102+x\approx\ln{2}+\ln{e^x}=\ln(e^x+e^x)$. So, the error is huge for $x\approx y $ and near zero

Answer (score 2):

You can use an approximation of max norm a.k.a. infinity norm with a p-norm of relatively high $p$.

Caveat #1: make sure $p$ isn't too high though because that can cause numerical instabilities, overflow to infinity, esp. if you use 32-bit floats

Caveat #2: norm works with the absolute values so you'll need to transform your numbers with e.g. `log(exp(x)+1)` (a.k.a. softplus) if you have to deal with negative values as well (and then back). Softplus quickly approximates $x$ for $x>20ish$ btw so this can be faster than it seems.